# Aligning complex images on a web page

Tags: html, css

What is the best way to position and align images on an HTML web page?

I will have approximately 10 user-controls that each have a set of images on them laid out in a specific pattern, eg - an arc, a circle, straight line, some other sort of curve.

All the images will be the same size.

How can I achieve this using best practices?

Comment: are the images the same size? If not the same size do they have the same ratios? Would they be poorly affected is stretched or shrunk to all be one size?

Comment: Hi, yes all the images will be the same size.

Comment: Do you want them layed out in a static configuration, or dynamically based on the size of the page or something (which would require javascript)?

Comment: A static configuration would suffice i think...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Absolute positioning is probably the way to go for something like that. With absolute positioning, you basically just define the x/y coordinates of each one. To position an element absolutely, you set `position: absolute;` in the CSS, and then `top: 5px;` and `left: 5px;` (that is, 5 pixels from the top, 5 from the left; you can also use bottom and right instead). Note that though it's called "absolute" positioning, which would make you think it's relative to the whole document, it's actually only relative to the first ancestor element with positioning other than `static` (static is the normal positioning mode). So if you wanted to contain a bunch in a parent and position it normally, you would set it to `position: relative;`, or you could position it absolutely as well. If no parent has non-static positioning, it will be relative to the whole page. Another thing to note, is that absolutely positioned elements don't take up any space, so for instance, if you've got a big element absolutely positioned, and the window is too small, there won't be scroll bars.

Comment: Let me know if you'd like an example (or more info).